# Need diffrent LEDS to turn on at diffrent levels of a potentiometer on arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, led

[the arduino and the breadboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBtHq.png)

if you look at the picture, I need each LED to turn on at diffrent stages of the potentiometer. so when it is at its first stage, the first LED from the left should turn on and light up, when the potentiometer gets to the second level the second led should turn on and turn off the previous LED and so on and so forth. i need this to work for all 5 LEDS and each of them should turn on and off individually. this is what I got so far. an answer would be appreciated and please keep the code fairly simple, there are quite a few errors in the code please forgive me as i am new this.

Thanks in advance

```
 // C++ code
//
int redLED = 13; //Pin numbers for the LEDS<br>int blueLED = 12;
int blueLED = 12;
int whiteLED = 11;
int yellowLED = 10;
int greenLED = 9;
int potent = A5; 
int potentNum = 0;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT); //Recognize the LEDS as OUTPUT
pinMode(blueLED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(whiteLED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(yellowLED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
}
 Serial.begin(9600);   //Begin the Serial Moniter

pinMode(potent, INPUT);
}
  void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  /*digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH); //Turn all the LEDS on
  digitalWrite(blueLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(whiteLED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(yellowLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);*/
  potentNum = analogRead(potent);    // gets value from sensor
  Serial.println(potentNum);
     delay(300);
  }
```

Comment: this is a project for my school, believe me i have tried several diffrent code all of which returning a error

Comment: Please see [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions](Asking about homework)

Answer (score 0):

Set the ports `HIGH` or `LOW` according to the value read from the analog port to turn ON or OFF the LEDs.

For example:

```
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  potentNum = analogRead(potent);    // gets value from sensor
  Serial.println(potentNum);
  digitalWrite(redLED, potentNum >= 171 ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite(blueLED, potentNum >= 341 ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite(whiteLED,potentNum >= 512 ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellowLED, potentNum >= 683 ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite(greenLED, potentNum >= 853 ? HIGH : LOW);
  delay(300);
}
```